# how to draw arrows in a literary text.

Tags: arrows, text, literate-programming

I would like to insert in a literary text some text like in the picture. To be honest, I have no any idea. Could you please me?

[image]

Comment: You might take a look at [TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf)

Comment: I have tried, but  i do not manage to create it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

with use of tikzmark library is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, tikzmark}

\begin{document}
text \tikzmark{As}text\tikzmark{Ae} text text text t\tikzmark{Bs}a\tikzmark{Be}xt

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\coordinate[below=0.5ex of $(pic cs:As)!0.5!(pic cs:Ae)$]  (a);
\coordinate[below=0.5ex of $(pic cs:Bs)!0.5!(pic cs:Be)$]  (b);
%
\draw (a) -- ++ ( 0,-1) node[draw,below, blue] {ABCDEFG};
\draw (b) -- ++ (-1,-1) node[below] {A};
\draw (b) -- ++ ( 0,-1) node[below] {B};
\draw (b) -- ++ ( 1,-1) node[below] {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

to obtain above image you need to compile at least twice.

since you didn't provide *mwe* (minimal working example), i construct own from one my  similar previous [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392984/tikz-arrow-direction/392998#392998). in text you mark place in text and later use marks' names to determine its coordinates in `tikzpicture`. for coordinates you should use `pic` syntax: `pic cs:<marker name>`.

to determine center of word or character are used two markers (named `As` and `Ae`, and `Bs` and `Be`, however you can select own names), one for mark beginning and one for end of word/ character. in drawing arrows is first calculated middle point between them and then add vertical offset.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Could you please explain me about *As*, *Bs*, *Ae*, *Be*. How should I proceed such that to obtain arrows instead of lines. thanks!

Comment: `As`, `Bs`, `Ae`, `Be` are names of markers. see edited answer.

Comment: I do not get how to draw arrows...

Comment: with `\draw[->]`, but if you like to have more fancy arrows heads, you should use tikz library `arrows.meta`.